# How are SW breakpoints handled by gdb-stub/server

Tags: gdb, gdbserver

How are SW breakpoints handled (conceptually) by gdb stub or server (I assume client stub and server handle them in pretty much same way)?
I'm interested in a 'bare metal' target where the gdb stub/server runs, and  both breakpoints and single stepping use software interrupts.

My actual questions:

When a breakpoint is hit, how is the stored instruction run so that the breakpoint can be 're-installed' and the (saved) machine status (including register contents) is not changed from the moment of hitting the breakpoint?
=>When is the breakpoint re-installed and how? Between breakpoint hit and entering the command interpreter, or during the next single step or coninue?

Also how does single-stepping over breakpoint work such that the original non-breakpoint instruction gets executed, and the breakpoint still remains there after being single-stepped over?

[edit]
Forgot: the document "GDB Internals" seems to be missing that info - and actually the whole subchapter about single stepping in the "Algorithms" chapter.

[edit2]
Ah, I seem to need stronger glasses: The 'Internals'-manual says:
"When the user says to continue, GDB will restore the original instruction, single-step, re-insert the trap, and continue on."

The single stepping over breakpoint, however, is still open question.

Answer (score 1):

> The single stepping over breakpoint, however, is still open question.

It's done exactly the same way as `continue`, except for the last step ("and continue on"). That is:

1. Process stops. GDB "looks around", discovers that `$ip` points to one of its breakpoints.
2. User issues `continue`, `next`, `step` or `stepi` command.
3. Restore original instruction (i.e. remove the breakpoint)
4. Single-step process
5. Re-insert breakpoint
6. Continue (this is done for `continue` but not for `next`, `step` or `stepi`).
7. For `stepi`, return control to the user (we are already at the next instruction due to step 4 above). For `next`, continue single-stepping until we reach a line in source that is not the same line we were on at step 1 above.

Comment: If it did like that, the replaced/restored instruction by single step would be trap (earlier by set breakpoint). That would cause breakpoint within single step.

Comment: @turboscrew You are mistaken, it *does* do it like that. Souce: I am a GDB developer. Single-step the process (step 4) means set `TF` flag in `EFLAGS` and continue. The processor will *automatically* execute one (original, restored in step 3) instruction, and stop.

Comment: "How are SW breakpoints handled " - no trap flag (btw, I'm not working with x86 or x86_64 family).   AAARGH, I got it: you meant removal of breakpoint by 'Restore original instruction'.

Comment: Darn, I couldn't select your answer as useful twice. This was news to me: " For next, continue single-stepping until we reach a line in source that..."